# PHPspreadsheet only saves "Sheet1" when xlsx but is ok when xls

Tags: php, excel, yii2, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I'm using PHPSpreadsheet to generate an XLSX file.
the code

```
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$full_filename = $path . $filename . '.xlsx';
$writer->save($full_filename);
```

When using the above code file only contains "Sheet1" and is blank but when I
use

```
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$writer = new Xls($spreadsheet);
$full_filename = $path . $filename . '.xls';
$writer->save($full_filename);
```

above code save the correct data with multiple sheets.

Saving XLSX used to work last week.

My server is:

> - Ubuntu  18.04 LTS
> - Mariadb 10
> - PHP 7.2.10 using Yii2 framework
> - using phpoffice/phpspreadsheet v. 1.3.1

Comment: please mention the extension that you are using in Yii2.

Comment: i'm using phpoffice/phpspreadsheet v. 1.3.1

Comment: somehow after ubuntu 18 update, it now works again saving xlsx